# Clearing a QWebView widget PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

I have a PyQt QWebView widget and need to clear the content of the widget. It displays a youtube video but I need to then remove the video from the QWebView to just display a blank page or just the original state of the widget.

Any ideas?
thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myQWebView.setHTML('')
```

You can additionally clear history:

```
myQWebView.history().clear()
```